# How to write to enviornment variables on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, environment-variables, env-file

I have made a website meant to me used by only one person, so I want to dynamically write to .env file on Heroku without it resting,
because this is meant only for one person. I don’t want to deal with a database.

Something like this:

```
require(`dotenv`).config();

console.log(process.env.MYVAL); // Not my value
process.env.MYVAL = "MYVAL"
console.log(process.env.MYVAL); // MYVAL
```

Comment: I’d suggest looking for other solutions. What about [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)?

Comment: Admitedly it is petty cool but i want to persist and not clear after cache reset  
and also the validition script is on the server side

Comment: #1 What is **website ment**? #2 Do you need to change any environment variable at runtime without restart? #3 Where are you using that vars? Just for render html with some template or to connect to a database?

Comment: #1 keeping a secret value to prove that it is the authorised user (hashed password)   
#2 yes - obiviously  
#3 you probably know where this is going

Comment: This is 100% an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627). Why do you want to do this? What are you trying to achieve? Environment variables are _not_ for maintaining state (and this will work particularly badly on Heroku where dynos get discarded all the time).

Comment: Please don't respond to people trying to help you for free with snarky comments like "yes - obviously". If it were obvious we wouldn't be asking for clarification. [Be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the heroku api to do that
but it will have to restart the dyno [Docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#config-vars)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the environment variables in the settings tab on your Heroku dashboard and also using the command line. Please check the following documentation to get more information.

*[Configuration and Config Vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)*

Comment: Yes i know that but thats not what i want
i want to overrite the env var MYVAL to "MYVAL" programmatically and envfile will not work as heroku's filesystem is ephirical and all changes will be reverted to orignal

Comment: @Ashwin, I assure you, any environment variables you set will _also_ be lost whenever your dyno restarts, just like the ephemeral filesystem. You cannot maintain state this way.

Comment: thats the problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to persist data (even if it is a single value). Therefore you should not write to Heroku file system nor storing it in environment variables (Heroku configuration variables).

I understand using a database could be not worth it, and in this case I would use an external file storage ([Amazon S3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_S3), [Dropbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropbox_%28service%29), and even using GitHub private repository).

On *[Files on Heroku](https://medium.com/geekculture/files-on-heroku-cd09509ed285)* you can see some options and (Python) code.

Comment: your answer is correct but any code samples to do it in node.js would be appreciated

Comment: I used Python and Java, but this is a good reference if you want to use Dropbox (you can have a free account), https://dropbox.tech/developers/writing-a-file-with-the-dropbox-javascript-sdk

Comment: hey just to notify you the dropbox.js link is broken and also i was intrested in github private repo

Comment: ah ok, I assumed dropbox as it is proper remote file storage. Using GitHub private repo is indeed possible, I have done this in Python but I am sure you can google/find an example in JS too. The workflow would be similar.

Comment: In your Medium blog post: 1) *Github* → *[GitHub](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=Github)* 2) *Gitlab* → *[GitLab](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=Gitlab)*